# Automatic shutdown after no activity

Tags: power-management, desktop

I've recently inherited maintenance of a couple of Linux based `internet kiosks` basically just Ubuntu with a graphical session locked into Firefox. Anyway is there a ready made solution for sending them into hibernate/shut down if no one has used them in say a couple of hours?

A cron job isn't flexible enough. I suppose i could do a script to see how long xscreensaver has been running but that'd be a kludge. And my google results weren't promising

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncommenting these lines:

```
IdleAction=hibernate
IdleActionSec=120min
```

If you want to shutdown, then use `poweroff` instead of `hibernate`.

Note: You need to restart your machine or restart systemd-logind service for the change to take effect.

Comment: Now if we can get a non-systemd solution this would be perfect

Comment: I was hopeful this would work for me but I set it to 5 minutes (to test) and 1 hour later EC2 was still up and running. Read the man page and it seems to indicate 'if' this, 'if' that. But out of the box it doesn't work for me (on an AWS Ubuntu AMI). Will need to keep using my 3:30 AM crontab shutdown.

Comment: @Jeach Have you tried doing it with [EC2 alarms](https://successengineer.medium.com/how-to-automatically-turn-off-your-ec2-instance-in-2021-b73374e51090)?